# VBScript Error 424 "Object Required"

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Does anyone know why the following mail-merge vb script would produce an error 424 - "object required"?

http://pastebin.com/93825YMi

The error occurs on line 41:

```
Set objTemplate = objWord.Documents.Open(sTemplate)
```

If I run the script from the command line it works fine. However, when it's started from a Windows service, it falls over when opening the Word document.

I've checked that the permissions are correct.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think a good way to find the fault is to remove the on error resume next statement from the top, and place just before the first error handling statement. I've always used option explicit and declared all variables and objects, so when an error occurs i find it easier to fix

Comment: Started by Windows service? Which user account?

Comment: What you get for `sTemplate` just before line 41? I hope it has full path to it. Also curious why don't you use `debugFile.WriteLine "..."` for those `debugFile.Write "..." & vbCrLf`?

Comment: I have almost the exact same problem. Script works when run from the command line but fails as a service. Did you ever find the solution?

Comment: I was having this issue and I found that, despite my insistence that I am indeed perfect, I misspelled a variable name.